# Gridview not updating inside updatepanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My gridview is inside an updatepanel, the gridview is not showing the updated data for some reason. Am i missing something? my code looks like the other examples i have found.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ColumnName="test" CssClass="auto-style14" EnableViewState="false" Font-Size="Medium" HorizontalAlign="Left" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="1010px">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField Text="Details" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CS:

```
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = visualDataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

Comment: This looks correct. The only reason I can think of why it wouldn't show anything is if your `visualDataTable` is empty.

Comment: What happens if you remove the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Visualdatatable is not empty, if I refresh the webpage the gridview updates..

Comment: You're going to need to create a [MCVE]. It needs to be more minimal (we don't need to see all your styling settings) and more Verifiable (you need to include enough parts to reproduce the issue, such as relevant Page_Load calls etc).

Comment: Are you updating GridView on a Button Click?

Comment: Gridview.datasource is being updated via a timer that re-runs the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set `AutoPostBack="true"` for you GridView and you should provide Triggers in UpdatePanel that'll update your GridView on a specific event, like in the following example:

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

Whenever this event will occur it'll update your GridView. Or In case you want to update your GridView on Button Click, you need to provide the following line of code inside your triggers:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" EventName="Click" />
```

Here is your Updated GridView:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView
      ID="GridView1"
      runat="server"
      AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
      BackColor="White"
      BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
      BorderStyle="None"
      BorderWidth="1px"
      CellPadding="3"
      ColumnName="test"
      CssClass="auto-style14"
      EnableViewState="false"
      Font-Size="Medium"
      HorizontalAlign="Left"
      AutoPostBack="true"
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
      Width="1010px"
    >
      <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Details" />
      </Columns>
      <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
      <HeaderStyle
        BackColor="#006699"
        BorderStyle="Solid"
        Font-Bold="True"
        ForeColor="White"
        HorizontalAlign="Center"
        VerticalAlign="Middle"
      />
      <PagerStyle
        BackColor="White"
        ForeColor="#000066"
        HorizontalAlign="Left"
      />
      <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
      <SelectedRowStyle
        BackColor="#669999"
        Font-Bold="True"
        ForeColor="White"
      />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
      <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger
      ControlID="GridView1"
      EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Does that trigger work automatically? I want the gridview to update when the timer on my code re-runs every 5 minutes. So I want it to update without user input.

Comment: Whenever `SelectedIndexChanged` will be called, UpdatePanel will be triggered, you should try this. Make sure `AutoPostBack` is set to true of `GridView`.

Comment: But that requires to for example click "select" before it's triggered right? If that's the case then it's not quite something I can use.. I need it to update as soon as visualdatatable is changed.

Comment: Then I suggest you should use `ASP Timer Control` and specify the time of 5 minutes to it and it will work for you.